# How would I go about proving these.

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove or disprove these two problems, but I'm not sure I did it right. 
$$(a).\quad   f(n) = 2^n+1 = O(2^n)\\
(b).\quad f(n) = 2^n+1 =  Θ(2^n) .$$

What I tried for the first one is, $2^n+1/2^n \le C$ when $K>1$, and then get stuck.

I think I'm just having trouble proving BigO

Comment: $2^n+1$ or $2^{n+1}$. Before the edit it was like $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Right right, I was actually just thinking that was why. Thanks.

Comment: $f(n)=O(2^n)$ even if $f(n)=2^n+1$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{n+1}\leq 3\times 2^n$ for all $n$. So, $2^{n+1}=O(2^n)$

Comment: That makes sense, is 3 the constant?

Comment: Yes. $C=3$ and $k=1$

Comment: And just so I understand how did you choose 3.

Answer (score 0):

$${2^{n}+1 \over 2^n}=1+{1\over{2^n}}\le 1+{1\over{2}}={3\over 2}$$ that is 
$$2^{n}+1\le {3\over 2}\times 2^n$$